# Express 4 app doesn't work in Azure when deployed via GitHub

Tags: node.js, azure, express, azure-web-app-service

I'm working on an Express app that I initially created from the Basic Azure Node.js Express 4 Application template in Visual Studio. In other words, [it has the `web.config` modifications necessary to support Express 4's `www\bin` structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23319774/deploying-express-4-x-app-to-windows-azure).

This app works fine when debugging via Visual Studio or running directly via Node command line. However, deployments from source control do not work when I hooked it up to the GitHub repo. I can see the project root in the `site\wwwroot` folder. Even more strange, publishing directly from Visual Studio works.

Comment: Ryan, do you see your node_modules folder with all the right packages in your site? Can you turn on logging via the "Diagnostics Logging" option in the Settings blade; then, check out your streaming logs? My theory is that it's an issue with the "npm install" that Websites does automatically when you git deploy a site. You can try turning on the git endpoint for your site and deploying using git from cmd line to see the error logs.

Comment: I did end up checking the deploy logs and diagnostic logs. No issues with deploy from package.Jason. Turns out it was my .gitignore file. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This turned out to be a simple oversight, but I feel that it can easily trip up others so I'll share the answer here. I'm using the [Visual Studio `.gitignore`](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore) file from GitHub and it includes a rule to ignore `[Bb]in/` as these are usually build output. My commits were not including the contents of `/bin`, so my continuous deployment obviously wasn't picking these up either. Simply commenting out this line fixed this issue.

Comment: Amazing, thanks dude - I spent a day on this issue but managed to fix it after coming across your post!